# Resend commerce email

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, emails, queue

We have a site that had a feature/plugin created that can handle payment deposits as well as full payments for events.

We're wanting to create a job (like a CRON Job) or process that once a week goes through orders that are deposit payments and checks if the event part paid for is within x weeks, if both of these are true then to send a templated email (if possible to include the link generated by commerce when the order was initial created).

Are there any guides or how-to's to do this?

Comment: I don't see a question - what have you tried so far?

Comment: My bad - didn't make it clear I was asking for pointers or guides to follow along. I'm currently going through the Craft Queue Jobs docs.